# How can I keep my animation file size low?

Tags: animation

I have an animation I'm working on with some fairly high poly assets that when put together will make the master animation file large.  Is there a way to incorporate those assets without contributing to file size?

Comment: "*How can I keep my animation file size low?*" Don't animate a lot. Other than that use the *File Compression* option the *User Preferences > File* tab

Comment: Ah thanks.  Didn't know that about the file compression.  When you say don't animate a lot, do you mean don't do long animations or use multiple assets?

Comment: I mean that if you are going to produce more data (animation, objects or otherwise) it will invariably require more space to store it regardless. There is no magical way around that, so I don't understand your question

Comment: I understand that but what I was wondering is if there is a way to use assets from other files to work on the animation, but not actually having it contribute to the file size.  Like caching an asset instead of appending it.

Comment: Well, you can Link objects from other files (File > Link), but then they'd be stored in _other_ files which would have the same combined size.

Comment: So in other words, if you were to link them it would affect the objects in the other files your are "borrowing" for your animation file?  Like if you made changes to object A in your animation file, it would make the exact same changes to object A in it's original file?